# Как снять галочки циклом с Checkbox если они находятся в нескольких уровнях контейнеров?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

Вот такая проблема. Если чекбоксы находились на одной wrappanel, то галочки я снимал вот так:

WPF:

```
<WrapPanel x:Name="wrapCheck">      
                             
   <CheckBox/>
   <CheckBox/>
           ...
   <CheckBox/>
 
</WrapPanel>
```

C#

```
foreach (CheckBox item in wrapCheck.Children.OfType<CheckBox>())
            {
                item.IsChecked = false;
            }
```

Но сейчас у меня чекбоксы находятся на одном wrappanel но каждый в разных grid, и так уже прошлый цикл не может к ним "достучатся".

WPF:

```
<WrapPanel x:Name="wrapCheck">
 
   <Grid>
      <WrapPanel> 
         <CheckBox/> 
      </WrapPanel>
   </Grid>
 
   <Grid>
      <WrapPanel> 
         <CheckBox/> 
      </WrapPanel>
   </Grid>
                            
                           
      ....
 
   <Grid>
      <WrapPanel> 
         <CheckBox/> 
      </WrapPanel>
   </Grid>
 
</WrapPanel>
```

Как в таком случае можно обратиться к чекбоксам через цикл? Заранее всем Спасибо!

Comment: Вы пытаетесь работать с интерфейсом из C# кода, это плохая практика, которая приводит к лишним сложностям. В WPF с инфтерфейсом в обычной ситуации не работают из C# кода вообще. Расскажите, какую исенно задачу вы решаете, зачем вам куча чекбоксов, и что вы хотите получить в итоге, тогда смогу что-нибудь подсказать. Ответ на ваш вопрос простой - "Используйте привязку данных", но пример не зная, чего вы хотите добиться, создать не смогу.

Comment: У меня программа по типу учёта склада продукции. Позиций товаров много. Каждый в отдельном чекбоксе. Пользователь выбирает нужны позиции нажимает кнопку "Проданы" и они отнимаются с базы данных. 

Из-за этого мне нужно что бы была проверка всех чекбоксов. У меня пока единственный вариант делать для каждого чек бокса отдельную проверку через If, но это будет ужас так как у меня 151 чекбокс)

Comment: В общем, так как вы пропали, ответ был удален как бесполезный. Очень странно задавать вопрос и исчезать никак не отреагировав.